# test subscr_payment using paypal ipn simulator

Tags: testing, paypal, paypal-ipn

I would like to test txn_type of 'subscr_payment' using paypal's ipn simulator.
but there is no such option.

[image]

while as you can see [here](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/Appx-ipn_subscription_variables.html) there is such txn type

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct; not all transaction types are currently supported in the IPN simulator.
We are planning to add more scenarios to the simulator, but for this kind of testing (which would require multiple successive IPN messages), I would recommend creating a subscription button in the sandbox environment and having it bill manually.

Unfortunately that's the only way to simulate subscription IPN messages today.

Comment: How do we test subscr_eot transaction types? As I know subscr_eot sends when a subscription expires. Is there a way to instantly expire a subscription profile?

Comment: Any update on this yet? It's a real pain in the rear doing subscription testing right now. Having to create a new subscription just to test the IPN incredibly tedious and wasteful. It means on my backend for this to work and to test it properly i have to create a new subscription, which means a new user and new account EVERY time i want to test the functionality of the IPN page. Why doesn't the IPN simulator support subscription payments? This question is over 4 months old. Please implement support for testing this. As a developer it's really needed.

Comment: Question is now well over a year old, still no support for this?

Comment: Still no support? I unsubscribed from Paypal Payments Pro because the API and documentation are so antiquated. Just another testament to that point.

Comment: Haha. Paypal is a joke.

Comment: And how can I bill it manually? I can't find this option inside subscription details page. The only way I can test this is setting biiling cycle to 1 day and waiting one entire day to see if my code is working fine... and, if it's not, wait another day... until everything is fine. That sucks.

Answer (score 5):

I also wonder if you can simulate subscription in IPN Simulator, but based on the choices, there is no way you can simulate subscription using IPN Simulator.

**The best way to simulate subscription is to create Sandbox test accounts**: one for the 'buyer' and one for the 'seller'. You can do this by going to **Paypal Developer** and go to *Applications* -> *Sandbox Accounts*.

My Sandbox test accounts: one for the buyer and one for the seller:
[image: My Sandbox test accounts: one for the buyer and one for the seller]

Once you have create the two test accounts, go to **Paypal Sandbox site**, login into your **buyer Sandbox test account** and create a Subscription Button. Wallah! You are done. **Note: make sure to set the billing cycle to 1 day only so that you quickly test your Paypal IPN Listener**.

Sandbox Subscription Button image:
[image: Sandbox Subscription Button image]

Email notifications to your Sandbox test accounts can be seen at the **[Sandbox account notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts)**.

Answer (score 5):

From within the PayPal developer site, you can go to the IPN simulator, select Transaction Type as Web Accept, click Show All Fields. You can then edit txn_type to be subscr_payment, subscr_signup, etc.

It's not perfect, as it doesn't give you all of the variables, but you can put info in other entries, and use a logical to determine whether or not the correct entry exists.

Do one test subscription, so that you have the values, and then work from there

Comment: Getting "IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Review your information." (scroll to top to see that message after hitting the send button). More here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32586711/1066234 - I couldn't fix it.