# PayPal IPN listener by WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, paypal, paypal-ipn

When i send test IPN by "Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Simulator" i get this:
"IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information."
In this case no reaction on the server is not happening :(
What am I doing wrong?
P.S. My server accessible from the Internet and nothing is blocking access. I asked a friend to send me a test message with Post request and my server accepted it. But on PayPal my method does not react at all!

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPayPalService
{
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/")]
   void Notify(Stream data);
}

public void Notify(Stream data)
{
}

<service name="PayPal.PayPalService">
   <endpoint address="http://myip:myport/PayPalService"
             binding="webHttpBinding"
             contract="PayPal.IPayPalService"/>
</service>
```

Comment: Why don't you mock a simple HTTP POST to it first and debug from there and figure out if your WCF is setup properly or if as the message indicates (you're not _properly_ handling).

Comment: I asked a friend to send me a test message with Post request and my server accepted it. But on PayPal my method does not react at all!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32644403/304683

Comment: I realized that I need to use supports SHA-256. But I tried everything and could not adjust my binding and behavior :(

Comment: To fix the error had to move this functionality to the site MVC.