# PayPal Error: IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified

Tags: paypal, openssl, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to get information from PayPal by using IPN (sandbox).

When I enter address:

```
https://my.site.com:4576/script.py
```

I get an error:

> paypal URL with port number is not allowed for IPN.

According to this [PayPal IPN on port other than 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838871/paypal-ipn-on-port-other-than-80) PayPal does not allow ports other than 80 and 443.
However when I change the address to:

```
https://my.site.com/script.py
```

I get an error:

> IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review
>   your information.

According to this [paypal IPN simulator getting error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363517/paypal-ipn-simulator-getting-error) this means that SSL is outdated however when I run this command `openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/`  in my server I get `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` which means that SSL is up to date.

How can I make this IPN work?

Comment: I've been having this problem, but to confuse matters further there are 3 sites on this server, all using cloned nginx conf & paypal button code, one works in the simulator and live fine, one works live but not in the simulator, and this new one doesn't work in either situation. For both failing in the simulator they are getting the handshake error. A lot of people are saying "Just go live, it works fine", which for our 2nd site was true (and may help others) but this latest one fails even with real money sent over.