# IPN Simulator: "IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information"

Tags: php, paypal, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I am struggling to get a paypal listener on my web server working.  I keep receiving the following error when trying to send a simple Web Accept from the **IPN Simulator: "IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information"**.  I am hosting a PHP script on an Amazon EC2 instance and have allowed the IP ranges for Paypal on the server.

I have been trying to update the G5 root certificate from Verisign on the server (a solution proposed on another post), however am unsure whether this is the root cause and have been unsuccessful in doing so anyway, as am getting a 'permission denied' when I try to copy the file in using scp.  If it is of use however for context the "openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath XXXX" command did yield "Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)" - which I assume is not good news.

If anyone has any advice on the issue I would be really grateful, as I have spent 10 hrs on this and have no further ideas!!  Let me know if I can provide any more information to help diagnose.

Thanks for your help

John

Comment: Some code replicating the issue would assist you in getting an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586711/ipn-was-not-sent-and-the-handshake-was-not-verified-please-review-your-informa)

Answer (score 0):

Having posted in desperation an hr ago, think this is now resolved - guess thats why they call it the 11th hr!  I made 2 simple changes:

1. Opened port 433, as well as 80
2. Used my Public DNS in the URL on the Paypal simulator as opposed to the Public IP

I really need to hit the books on this stuff, as am a terrible web admin!

Thanks for everyone who read this - Mick thanks for your note..

Comment: I found out that opening 443 is not necessary; all what is needed is to use DNS-based URLs, and NOT IP-based URLs. IP-based urls do not work and will result in the abovementioned error.