# PayPal IPN Handshake fails. IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information

Tags: node.js, ssl, paypal, paypal-ipn

This is not a duplicate issue I have read through all of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633965/ipn-simulator-ipn-was-not-sent-and-the-handshake-was-not-verified-please-rev) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586711/ipn-was-not-sent-and-the-handshake-was-not-verified-please-review-your-informa) and more.

I have setup a ELB on amazon to test IPN from [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/)

Then I have verified SSL certificates:

```
openssl s_client -connect payments-staging.******.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.buddybid.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 3 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.*****.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 6059 bytes and written 421 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 7490AFBBC42CF60A6B44D760A2FB977D768D13DB78515D0C54081E979397E47D
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 583A2D57EF3339B97E37E17CFA0E3A17173FF3B3BB97231477ACDD97D2CC02886A6B04B21DC3109E5B4BE0913ED79145
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 90 4a 48 33 b9 ff 8a 5c-a9 cd 2a 79 89 38 7b 7c   .JH3...\..*y.8{|
    0010 - 91 62 72 de 8f 1e 57 b3-98 99 70 69 35 96 a7 f8   .br...W...pi5...
    0020 - c5 26 1b eb 59 75 63 9c-c6 1b b4 be 91 5f a0 70   .&..Yuc......_.p
    0030 - fd 6e c4 fc 6e 25 7d d7-7d 51 9f 5e 22 03 1a 91   .n..n%}.}Q.^"...
    0040 - a2 ec 42 73 48 e4 e4 70-5d 1a 10 b9 38 d3 60 c9   ..BsH..p]...8.`.
    0050 - 9e 42 47 d4 02 dc a5 91-75 c6 b8 80 27 32 ce 52   .BG.....u...'2.R
    0060 - 26 85 56 eb 46 d5 a2 be-a9 1e 74 17 05 84 b0 fb   &.V.F.....t.....
    0070 - cb 34 06 b4 02 d7 a3 0b-76 21 78 c8 2d b3 e3 6a   .4......v!x.-..j
    0080 - 7e 57 52 7e d7 32 6d 76-0c 50 00 bd 79 aa 3a e3   ~WR~.2mv.P..y.:.
    0090 - 20 7d 27 96 97 d9 ea 3d-67 54 b9 f4 bf d8 f2 b6    }'....=gT......

    Start Time: 1453929662
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
closed
```

Then I went and validated ciphers/security via ssllabs.com with [this results](http://screencast.com/t/IhV0hhDg6U) (A) is sent.

and yet no IPN

I have spent 2 days on this issue and really would appreciate if someone can shine some light on this. Very frustrating and funny enough PayPal using [stackoverflow](https://developer.paypal.com/support/) as their ticketing system which I find really lame as I can't expose here business information.

I'm sure there are must be a lot of people out there who has the same issue.

Comment: Where is the evidence for 'IPN handshake fails' and 'handshake was not verified'?