# g5 certificate and paypal ipn simulator testing issues

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

CentOS release 6.6
 running httpd & php for webserver

We have a working paypal IPN processing script, however when we went to move it  to a new directory and test in the paypal IPN simulator we got the error:

"IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information."

Trying to debug this led us to:
 [IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586711/ipn-was-not-sent-and-the-handshake-was-not-verified-please-review-your-informa)

Following the advice in the stockoverflow post when we run:
 openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/pki/tls/certs/

We get:
 Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

We have installed the g5 certificate:
 [root@li375-212 testing]# awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '/BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt | grep "G5"
 subject= /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5

However we still get the Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate) after running the openssl command listed above