# Set G5 root certificate on my localhost

Tags: ssl, paypal, ssl-certificate

I'm using Apache on my localhost for testing.

I tried to use PayPal IPN simulator but I get this error:

`IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.`

I have set up a DNS name on **dynu** as I have heard that public IP URL will not work.

I have seen this question
[IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586711/ipn-was-not-sent-and-the-handshake-was-not-verified-please-review-your-informa)

so I know I have to have Versign G5 root cert / SHA-2.

Since I'm new at this can someone explain what do I have to do to put valid certificate on my server?

What steps to take?

Do I need to pay for certificate or there is some free solution that I can use for testing?

I have been here

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US

they don't say anything concrete.

I'm, using Apache 2.4 on Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Did your script capture the IPN data when using IPN simulator? It is possible that the IPN was indeed delivered but the postback verification process fails.

Comment: If your script didn't receive any IPN data, then it could be caused by absence of your server SSL certificate. That is, IPN is sent to a HTTPS url but no valid certificate presented by your server during handshake. Hence, IPN cannot be sent. This one is basically the one you need to pay.

Comment: If your script received the IPN data, then postback to PayPal server could fail. In this case, you will need to install or make sure PayPal root cert installed in your server. The instruction varies on which OS you use, but you can get the root cert here: https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/mpki-for-ssl-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO5624

Comment: I have simple script that just opens some file and writes to it. New file appears when I load script in my browser. Nothing happens when I click "Send IPN" on the Simulator. That is why I think that script did not receive any IPN data whatsoever.

Comment: I have seen that root cert from that link, but how do I use that? I'm really new at this and I have Googled but I see only root cert, no private key. So can you tell me how to use it? I have to copy-paste it and than what next?